# Direct all requests to Public directory from .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . public/$1  [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have tried this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

None of them working properly. Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: "none of them working properly" - What IS happening? Error messages? Routing to a particular file? Etc.

Comment: I've never wrapped my `.htaccess` code in an `<IfModule>`... I just put the rules right into the `.htaccess`. I'm no expert on it, though.

Comment: This or a similar tool can also be helpful for debugging htaccess: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ Your rules look like they should be working... You might need a `DirectoryIndex`, if the url is pointing to a directory and not a file.

Comment: Question: Why do you want to redirect to a public folder? Where is your .htaccess file located?

Comment: You need to edit your question to include more information. Where is your `.htaccess` file? What URLs are you requesting? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files? Is mod_rewrite enabled? Are `.htaccess` overrides enabled in your server config?